# change image and link on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

When a user hovers my `navigationbar`, the image and the text must change of color. I'm using a sprite for the images.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="nav_logo"><img src="images/lch.png" width="302" height="114" alt="LCH"></li>
    <li id="nav_over_lch"><a href="index.html"><span></span> OVER LCH </a></li>
    <li id="nav_nieuws"><a href="index.html"><span></span>NIEUWS</a></li>
    <li id="nav_activiteiten"><a href="index.html"><span></span>EVENTS</a></li>
    <li id="nav_fotos"><a href="index.html"><span></span>FOTO 'S</a></li>
    <li id="nav_contact"><a href="index.html"><span></span>CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I already have some CSS:

```
li#nav_over_lch span{background-position: 0 0;} 
li#nav_over_lch span:hover{background-position: 0 -50px;}
#nav li a {color:#1f1f1f; text-decoration:none; font-size:40px; font-family: 'headline_onehplhs'; display: block; text-align: center;}
#nav li a:hover{color:#006699;}
```

This is the piece of the CSS that changes the image and text. So far it changes both when you hover the text but only the images when you hover the images.
Any ideas how to make this possible in (cross-browser) CSS?

Comment: this is pure `CSS` problem, no need for `jQuery` I think. Also jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnGhp/). I quiet don't get the question. There is only one picture in whole `<ul>` or there are on each `<li` ? It is not clear from information provided.

Comment: Every <li> has a single image that can change if you hover it. I want to change them both when you hover one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put hover on the element you want the hover to be on

```css
li#nav_over_lch span{background-position: 0 0;} 
li#nav_over_lch:hover span{background-position: 0 -50px;}
#nav li a {color:#1f1f1f; text-decoration:none; font-size:40px; font-family: 'headline_onehplhs'; display: block; text-align: center;}
#nav li:hover a{color:#006699;}
```

Comment: That's the perfect solution. Thnx!